Background jobs Nodejs Minikube
I am trying to do some background jobs in Nodejs (Express). First I tried Bull package which works along with Redis. Then I tried BullMQ and then node-cron package. All of these solutions work on development without any problem. When I make some services in Kubernetes Minikube local machine, none of these solutions work. There is no error and no job executed (one exception, one job out of 50 jobs got executed ones). I do not know what can be wrong because there is no error. The corresponding code should be ok because it works on development without any problem and my services are ok because all pods are running without any problem or restart.  I might miss something obvious but I am new to the world of Kubenetes. Any idea why background jobs not working in Minikube?

@ Tjax  Refer to this Stack link also about Background processes in Node.js.

Follow this  Dev   Article  by Sam  for more information about Node.js background job processing with bull - basics
There are multiple reasons why your background jobs are not working in Minikube. Follow troubleshooting steps to resolve your issue.

Verify whether the bull or bullmq processes are being destroyed because of the limited resources, you can check this by using kubectl describe pod command to check whether the pods go through a restart or termination in a short while.
Minikube is resource constrained as compared to the production environments.Ensure your minikube setup has enough CPU,Memory and network resources for background jobs.
Check that your Minikube setup has sufficient resources for background jobs.
Check that your services have been exposed correctly via kubernetes services and can be reached from your Node. js application.
Make sure minikube clusters have sufficient network connections to the services provided. You may want to check the firewall rules as well.
-Use logging  and debugging techniques to check the status of background processes.

See this Medium blog   for more  information about Message Queue in Node.js with BullMQ and Redis.
